# Unsure why psql says table is empty but tableplus returns rows

Tags: postgresql, data-integrity, table-plus

What am I missing?

[image: screenshot of both results]

I've connected on console to a DB I have populated with data, using a socket connection. I've validated that the table in question has the rows I expect. When I try and run a `SELECT` statement in `psql` the response comes back with a summary of the table columns and "(0 rows)" but when I query the table in any other tool (rails console, TablePlus) I see all of the data I expect. TablePlus/rails are also configured to connect via socket. I've made sure to log in to the same user account for all three.

Here is how I am connecting via `psql`:
[image: psql connection info]

And here is my Tableplus connection setup:

[image: TablePlus connection info]

Comment: You're most likely connected to different databases or using different search paths for the different queries. Without the exact connection information, hard to help you

Comment: I kind of wondered if that was somehow the case; I'm not sure how I'd have identical tables if I'm in different DBs. I'll add the connection strings to the queries in just a minute, thank you!

Comment: I've updated the question with summaries of the connections I've used. In the console example I'm connecting as the user `aaron` and in the Tableplus case as the user `postgres`, but I have also tried `su postgres` in console and connected as that user and see the same results when I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks very much to Frank Heikens' answer above, I eventually noticed that Tableplus doesn't explicitly clarify how it's connected by default, and it lists `127.0.0.1` as the connection it is using rather than a socket address. I tried adding `-h 127.0.0.1` in the console when connecting with `psql` and was indeed able to view the data I expected. It looks like I forgot that I installed Postgres locally way back and then later migrated to connecting to a docker instance, apparently via a network connection rather than a socket file shared to my hard drive like I had thought.

So, to sumamrize: I was indeed connecting to different DBs. In the first case using psql I was connecting to a Postgres instance running natively on Ubuntu, and with TablePlus/ruby on rails connecting to a Docker Postgres instance via local networking.

Comment: You might want to confirm this by looking at the [listen_addresses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) settings in the respective `postgresql.conf` files.